# Clear Text Box Value and Reset all Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For the following code:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#error_msg').hide();
    });
     //When user clicks enter button
    function clickenter() {
        text = document.getElementById('text_one').value;
        if (text == "" || text == null || text.length > 50) {
            $('#error_msg').show('slow');
            return false;
        } else {
            $('#list').append('<li>' + text + '</li><br />');
            text == "";
        }
    };
     //When user presses Enter
    document.getElementById('text_one').onkeypress = function (e) {
        if (!e) e = window.event;
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == '13') {
            text = document.getElementById('text_one').value;
            if (text == "" || text === null || text.length > 50) {
                $('#error_msg').show('slow');
                return false;
            } else {
                $('#list').append('<li>' + text + '</li><br />');
                text == "";
            }
        }
    };
    $('#error_mssg_x').click(function () {
        $('#error_msg').hide('slow');
    });
```

How would I go about setting the value of the text to nothing when the function runs? I looked around and saw that setting the value of it equal to "" would do the trick but it doesn't seem to be working.

I would also like to add a 'Clear' button but I'm not quite sure how I would approach doing so. All the items get appended to these HTML elements:

```
    <div id="title_box">
        <ul id="list"></ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: text_one is the id for the text box where the user enters the information

Answer (score 0):

on `text == "";`

Try using only one equal sign `=`

Answer (score 0):

You should assign `text = "";`

Also for reseting value in `#list` id, you can use

```
document.getElementById('#list').innerHTML = "";
```

This will clear your all appended value in list.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('text_one').onkeypress = function (e) {
        if (!e) e = window.event;
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == '13') {
            text = document.getElementById('text_one').value;
            if (text == "" || text === null || text.length > 50) {
                $('#error_msg').show('slow');
                return false;
            } else {
                $('#list').append('<li>' + text + '</li><br />');
                document.getElementById('text_one').value = "";
            }
        }
    };
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/chankeypathak/z3d48/2/)

Edit: Since you also asked for a button to clear both `textbox` and `ul`, I've added another function. Check the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/chankeypathak/z3d48/3/).

```
<button id="clear">clear</button>

$( "#clear" ).click(function() {
    document.getElementById('text_one').value = "";
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = "";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put together some samples. You would want to access the input element using a jquery selector where you can work with the val() method. Setting the .val("") will set the text to "empty". Here's some sample to get you started (tried to reuse some names where possible).

Also you notice in your code you have the same code doing the same thing? "if(text="" || ...). I consolidated that into one function to be called by either the keypress or the button click. Put a fiddle at the end.

Markup

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="text_one" placeholder="Enter Value Here" />
    <input type="button" id="btnclick" value="Add" />
    <input type="button" id="btnclear" value="Clear List" />
</div>
<div id="ErrorMessage" style="display: none;">
    You entered an invalid value&nbsp;<span id="DismissError" style="cursor: default;">&times;</span>
</div>
<div>
    <ul id="listItems"></ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript using jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("#btnclick").click(function(){
        enterValue();
    });
    $("#text_one").keypress(function(e){
        if ( e.which == 13 ) {
            enterValue();
        }
    });
    $("#DismissError").click(function(){
        hideError();
    });
    $("#btnclear").click(function(){
        clearList();
    });
});
function enterValue(){
    hideError();
    var value = $("#text_one").val();
    if(!value || value.length > 50){
        return doError();
    }
    $("#listItems").append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
    $("#text_one").val("");
}
function doError(){
    $("#ErrorMessage").show();
}
function hideError(){
    $("#ErrorMessage").hide();
}
function clearList(){
    $("#listItems").html("");
}
```

JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4uxaP/1/